# Simple Javascript - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, html

Seems like this is a pretty common error, but being that I'm new to this I have no idea how to actually fix it. It's suppose to change the text on the page to what's in the input box once I click the button. Files are in the right directories so I know that's not the problem.
HTML Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Learning JavaScript</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/index.js"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input id='myInput' type='text' value='test' />
    <button id='stylesChanger'> Change the text!</button>
    <div id='firstDiv'>This is some text </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript Code:

```
var newText=document.getElementById("myInput").value;

document.getElementById("stylesChanger").onclick=function() {
  document.getElementById('myInput').value;
  document.getElementById("firstDiv").innerHTML=newText;
}
```

Comment: Your code is working : https://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/567/

Comment: try adding your `<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/index.js"> </script>` after the `<body>` ends.

Comment: @sdespont that's because jsfiddle is putting the code in a "load" handler. The code in the OP will run before the DOM is loaded.  Also note that if you actually type something into the input and *then* click the button, you don't get the new value.

Comment: Weird it just doesn't work for me when I open it into chrome